# Email Push authentication for JAVA Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, email

I have a web application running on Apache Tomcat. I have used JDBC realm to perform the authentication. 
Now, I have to develop a module that can perform the following functionalities in order:

1. When an user tries to Log-in to his/her account send an E-mail to the users Email id (present in the database);
2. The Email states that someone is trying to Log-in to the user's account and contains a link that redirects to a new page that prompts 2 options: "YES" or "NO";
3. If the user presses "YES", my web application must allow the user to Log-In and access his/her homepage; else the web application must abort the Log-In process and prompt an error message.

So this is *kinda similar to Google Authentication*. Is there a way this can be done? Are there any API's that provide this type of functionality?

**Any ideas on how to proceed?**

Comment: What's the point in picking "NO"? One could just refuse to login on the next screen...

Comment: "NO" can be used when Login is attempted by someone else other than the said user.

Comment: Ok, but what's the point? If I'm not the user and I arrive at that screen I'll never feel guilty and press "NO".... Also, I wouldn't know the user/pass....

Comment: The email is not sent to person who tires to log-in. The email must be sent to the user's Email id present in the database. During the time of registration I will ask the user to enter his/her email and I will store it in the DB along with other details. I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: So you are saying that the "*yes or no*" email (Which I suggest you to rename "*Authorize*" and "*Block*") is sent to a different person? Like, a supervisor that must authorize the person?

Comment: Imagine I am the user, I try to log-in to my account. The moment I press Log-in, I get a mail with a link. Upon clicking it, I am redirected  to a page asking me whether the log-in was attempted by me or not. I click "YES" and I am Logged-In. Now you are another person, you come to know of my password and try to log-in. Now I receive the same email again. Now, I click "NO" because it was not me who attempted to log-in.So now you are shown an error stating "Log-In Failed".

Comment: I get it now. So basically it is a two-step login, as Google's.

I suggest you to generate a key at first login attempt, use the key to generate the link. The confirmation page sends "yes" or "no" to that key's  login attempt.

So you should also store on the database the login attempts (their status (pending, approved, refused), and their keys).

Comment: Yeah. That is why I mentioned "Similar to Google Authentication" in my question. How to generate a link that can be accessed across multiple devices? This is small web app and I am running it locally in Tomcat. If you know/ come to know of any API's that can be use to perform this operation over the internet, it would be better.

Comment: [GET](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) requests allows you add parameters to a link. If you are not familiar with them, consider that when you see an URL, the final part after the `?` are all parameters passed to the page. For instance the URL `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DfQnOq1e9K4` is a GET request to the page `watch` that sends the parameter `v` with value `DfQnOq1e9K4`